# MDX query containing 2 dimensions from the same Hierarchy

Tags: mdx, adomd.net

The relevant structures from my cube are that I have a Hierarchy with "Class" and "SubClass". I also have a Measure called "Value" which is what im trying to obtain.

A simple query may look like:

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY ([Measures].[Value]) ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY ([Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class]) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

And I can obviously read the SubClass using the HIerarchy which is returned to Adomd.

My issue is twofold, firstly how would I "flatten" this hierarchy so as to receive both Class and SubClass as discrete members in the CellSet? This does not work:

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY ([Measures].[Value]) ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY (
   [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class], 
   [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Sub Class]
) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

> The Class Hierarchy hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function

Second issue, what I actuually need to do is filter the above on particular classes, again this wont work for the same reason as above.

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY ([Measures].[Value]) ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY (
   {[Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class].&[ClassA],[Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class].&[ClassB]}, 
   [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Sub Class]
) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

Any help much appreciated. MDX is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the MEMBERS property on your dimension.

For your first example try this:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY ([Measures].[Value]) ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {(
            [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class].MEMBERS,
            [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Sub Class].MEMBERS)} ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

For your second example try this:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY ([Measures].[Value]) ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY {(
            [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class].&[ClassA],
            [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Class].&[ClassB],
            [Some Dimension].[Class Hierarchy].[Sub Class].MEMBERS)} ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but im afraid its wrong. This produuces the same error "The Class Hierarchy hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function"

Comment: Sorry. It works just fine on my cube. Double check that you have the curly braces and parenthesis in the right spots. I'm a bit confused that you talk about a crossjoin function but it's not in your sample MDX. Typically it's denoted by the * between dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure your Cube has the 2 dimensions on the same Hierarchy? I can also ssee no difference between using a * for crossjoins from a comma.

I have double checked the order of curlies & parenthesis in my query, same result.

I have tried replacing the comma by * with same result.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was using the attribute hierarchies directly instead of hierarchies. That's what the above will work with. I think cross joins across used defined hierarchies aren't supported.

Comment: Thanks for the info and your help with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use Subqueries in your WHERE Clause. 
MDX will always restrict the use of one dimension on one Axis only.

Sub Query is a way to get around that. I recently learnt this trick after MDX drove me nuts as well..

Comment: can you give an example of using Sub Query in this context pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this query worked for me.

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[App Count] }
 ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY 
 {(
 EXISTING 
 (
 [MART TIME DIM].[Date].[Date] .MEMBERS) * 
 [New Ren DIM].[New Ren CODE].[New Ren CODE].ALLMEMBERS
 )}
 ON ROWS FROM [SubmissionCube]  
 where
({
[MART BROKER DIM].[BROKER ID].&[10812]},{[MART TIME DIM].[Year].&[2015],
{[MARTTIME DIM].[Year].&[2016]}
})
```

Please be carefull with the '}' in the where clause as the query has.

Comment: I am using [MART TIME DIM].[Year].&[2015]

Comment: I am using [MART TIME DIM].[Year].&[2015] and  
[MART TIME DIM].[Year].&[2016] and it yeilds me the result for the two years

Comment: Wow, 7 years old to the day.